# Why is the Display Setting for "Scaling" and the use of more than 1 monitor causing my WPF app window to animate in a different area on my monitor?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, multiple-monitors, doubleanimation

I am currently working on a WPF application that lives on the right side of the primary monitor. It starts as a tab and when clicked, slides off screen and then slides back out as a form to fill out. The issue that I am facing is that when the Scaling Setting on a monitor is set to anything but 100% and I have more than 1 monitor in use, the application runs the animation at a different position on the monitor before returning to its original poisition. This also happens when the application is collapsed back into a tab. I have attached 2 videos that display the behavior (the animation at 100% scaling and 150% scaling), along with a screenshot of the Scaling setting.

**Display Scaling setting from the Windows Display Menu:**

[image: Display Scaling setting from the Windows Display Menu]

**Animation with Monitor set to 100% scaling:**

[image: Animation with Monitor set to 100% scaling]

**Animation with Monitor set to 150% scaling:**

[image: Animation with Monitor set to 150% scaling]

Is there a way to prevent this issue from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to animate a window and as i've researched, i've found that its not a good idea. The framerate is never good. And its affected by the scaling setting. My window is now just an invisible shell and I am now just animating the X Property of the RenderTransform of the object that hold all of my content in my app and it does a better making it seems as if the application is disappearing offscreen.

[Fixed Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FHp6.gif)